# words for snail

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, dialects

I have seen かたつむり and でんでんむし and ででむし listed as "snail." What are the differences between these words?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are dialectal forms, but it could be said that three synonymous forms かたつむり, でんでんむし, and まいまい have gained more or less nation-wide recognition today. The situation is somehow similar to that "[soda/pop/coke](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6926/157006)" tripartition in USA.

The name of snail has been a signature of Japanese dialectology since the pioneering work [『蝸牛考』](http://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/1823865) written in 1930 by [Kunio Yanagida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunio_Yanagita). The summary of this book is that dialectal forms distribute in concentric circles from Kyoto, so that the remotest place maintains the oldest form.

> (newer/nearer to Kyoto → older/farther)
>   デデムシ > マイマイ > カタツムリ > ツブリ > ナメクジ ([source](http://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/1823865/103))

A very detailed survey on word forms of "snail" conducted by 国立国語研究所 was compiled into three atlas (No. [1](https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/s_data/drep/laj_map/LAJ_236.pdf), [2](https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/s_data/drep/laj_map/LAJ_237.pdf), [3](https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/s_data/drep/laj_map/LAJ_238.pdf)) if you seek further understanding. (Tons of local forms recorded.)

I (and most people living in Tokyo) would use かたつむり most often.

Comment: broccoli forest: >dialectal forms distribute in a concentric circle from Kyoto, so that the remotest place maintains the oldest form.--Very interesting and clever method to infer the fact by going back in time just like one in search of what was just after the Big Bang.

Comment: the same sort of reasoning is widely used in dialectology worldwide, and it has been used to argue that [Kyoto-type pitch accent is actually newer than Tokyo-type](http://www.jstor.org/stable/132278), not older as commonly claimed (so-called "Kantō-type" is also present west of Kansai, spreading outwardly in concentric circles, going as far as Kyūshū and Tōhoku; even certain isolated mountain villages within Kyoto use it).

Comment: I think I just understood why my wife calls me a "コタツムリ"...